# How do I add magento frontend css to backend?

Tags: php, magento, include-path, adminhtml

I have a block, which is appearing in the backend, and is adding a css file via the usual command:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->addCss('mymodule/css/filename.css');
```

And this should work, except that it is only looking for the file in skin/adminhtml - and I want to include the file from skin/frontend, because that is where it currently resides.

I am overcoming this temporarily by the brute force measure of copying the file from `skin/frontend/default/mymodule/css/filename.css` to `skin/adminhtml/default/mymodule/css/filename.css`, but I would rather refer to it directly. Is there some way to make the addCss command look in frontend instead of adminhtml?

Comment: FYI, Magento now has its own StackExchange site: http://magento.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

If it is indeed a *new* CSS file for a custom module, it should reside in *skin/adminhtml/default/default/css/*, like any of the other distinct skin assets.

***Edit** based on OP comment:*

Because it is *your* new file, you *can* switch the area for the `core/design_package` instance from **adminhtml** to **frontend** and then revert it. However, my preference or expectation would be to see a stylesheet under *skin/adminhtml/default/default/* which calls

```
@import('../../../frontend/base/default/css/file.css');
```

For this use case there isn't an absolute best practice, so it's up to you.

Comment: No, it already exists. The problem is that I am currently using it for the frontend, and I now want to use it for the backend as well, so my question is how I can do this without copying the file.